# use jackson serialize, How can I serialize double value null and not return when 0.0

Tags: java, json, jackson, double, serialization

I try to implement custom `Jackson` serializer, and also I want to handle double value when equals `0.0`, `writeNull()`, and not return.
Here is my serializer code

```
public class DoubleGTZeroSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {

  private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

  @Override
  public Class<Double> handledType() {
    return Double.class;
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (value != null && value.doubleValue() > 0) {
      gen.writeString(df.format(value));
    } else {
      gen.writeNull();
    }
  }
}
```

the below is pojo

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Bill implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5034123031564773631L;

  @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleToStringSerializer.class)
  private Double orderFee;

  @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleToStringAfterSymbolSerializer.class)
  private Double transFee;

  @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleToStringBeforeSymbolSerializer.class)
  private Double otherFee;

  @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleGTZeroSerializer.class)
  private Double gtZeroFee;
 ...
}
```

and my request is 
http://localhost:5509/test?orderFee=10.1&transFee=100.00&otherFee=&gtZeroFee=0
the api result

```
{
    "status": {
        "desc": "操作成功",
        "code": 0
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "orderFee": "10.1",
            "transFee": "100元",
            "gtZeroFee": null
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

I don't want to out put the `gtZeroFee` with null, but the annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` not works, please help me, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL` you can use `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` and implement [isEmpty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html#isEmpty-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider-T-) method:

```
class DoubleGTZeroSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {

    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

    @Override
    public Class<Double> handledType() {
        return Double.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(df.format(value));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, Double value) {
        return value <= 0;
    }
}
```

and change `Bill` annotation to:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
class Bill implements Serializable {
```

Comment: @zhaolibin, in case answer was helpful, you can always accept it and upvote (if you have enough points to do that). See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)