# Serialize flat object to nested JSON structure

Tags: java, json, groovy, jackson

### Challenge

I have a completely flat (POGO/POJO) object which I need to serialize into a nested JSON structure. Preferably using Jackson annotations and/or a custom Serializer

I'm only interested in serializing from object to JSON, deserializing is not needed.

### Example

I would like to turn this class:

```
class SomeClass {
    @JsonProperty('Business.Name')
    BigDecimal prop1 = 42.0
    @JsonProperty('Other.Nested.Business.Name')
    BigDecimal prop2 = 3.14
}
```

Into this JSON:

```
{
  "Other" : {
    "Nested.Business.Name" : 3.14
  },
  "Business.Name" : 42.0
}
```

### Catch 22

The code for the class is auto-generated. I have *some* influence over the generation, but it needs to be completely flat!

Any help would be much appreciated!

### Additional info

I already tried making a custom serializer, but failed to write the nested structure.

```
class SomeClassSerializer extends StdSerializer<SomeClass> {
    void serialize(SomeClass value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
        jgen.writeStartObject()
        jgen.writeNumberField("Business.Name", value.prop1)
        //how to write the nested structure
        jgen.writeEndObject()
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it says // how to write the nested structure, have you tried something like

```
   jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("Other")
   jgen.writeNumberField("Nested.BusinessName", value.prop2)
   jgen.writeEndObject()
```

Comment: I just have and it works! 
But I need to remove fields and entire sub-structures if it only contains null-values, and thats apparently a problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449681/how-to-remove-null-values-generated-by-a-jackson-custom-serializer

Comment: @brianjohnsen Wrap the writing in ifs?

Comment: @cfrick what is ifs?

Comment: `if (value.props2) { ... }`

Comment: Of course if-statements, I read it as an acronym :-)
Unfortunately thats way too cumbersome, as nested structures can contain 20-30 fields, and if none has value the surrounding structure must not be there either.

Comment: I'm accepting Thomas answer. Unfortunately I can't use it because of the null-issue. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score -1):

You can write just custom serializer: `JsonSerializer<SomeClass>` to define all rules.

Comment: I updated question with failed custom serializer attempt